# Angular.js $resource data processing

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a server side REST api, which can return a jsonyfied data with arbitrary structure. On a client side I have an Angular application.

Resource is defined:

```
module.factory('SearchQueries', function ($resource){          
   return $resource('/instances/searches/:_id', {_id: '@_id'}); 
})
```

After I try to get data from my api:

```
$scope.search_queries = SearchQueries.query(null, function(args){  
  console.log('success: ', args);                                  
  for (i in args) {                                                
  }                                                                
});
```

The client side receives a data with kinda structure:

`{"2": "serfgserg", "3": "sdfgdfg", "4": "sdgdfhdfghfgh", "5": "sdgdfhdfghfgh"}`

But! In the success function of the Angular resource every symbol of the data is the value of one element object.

`[{"0":"s","1":"e","2":"r","3":"f","4":"g",` e.t.c

Why is it done? How to prevent or use it rightly?

## edit:

If I return an array from the server:

```
res = json.dumps(["sdf", "asdf", "asdf"])                             
return Response(response=res, mimetype='application/json',
        status=status)
```

Never mind I have the same result:

```
[{"0":"s"},{"0":"d"},{"0":"f"},{"0":"a"},{"0":"s"},{"0":"d"},{"0":"f"} // e.t.c
```

Comment: Does your server return about valid json?
Does your server return back "application/json"?

Comment: Yes it is. Answer has edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happends beacause `query` expects an array of objects, not an object - see [the ngResource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}

expects something like:

```
[{"name":"sdf"}, {"name":"asdf"}, {"name":"asd"}]
```

Comment: I've clarified my answer, you should return an array of objects

Comment: Thanks! Why is it modified instead of just get data or except it if data format is not valid? This is strange for me and I really want to know what for is it done?

Comment: A resource doesn't really make sense unless it's an object. Every object in your array will inherit the SearchQueries prototype object (with methods as $save and $delete). You should also check out the [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http).